# How can I connect AWS glue connection to MongoDb in Atlas which is hosted on Goolge Cloud Platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Hi I am facing trouble in crawling Mongo data to S3 using a crawler from AWS-Glue. In Mongo Atlas you need to whitelist IPs that it expects connections from. As Aws-Glue is serverless I do not have any fixed IP as such. Please suggest any solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the document: [Connecting to a JDBC Data Store in a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/populate-add-connection.html#connection-JDBC-VPC), AWS Glue jobs belong to the specified VPC ( and the VPC has NAT gateway ) should have a fixed IP address. For example, after configured a NAT gateway for the VPC, HTTP requests from the EC2 server belongs to the VPC has fixed IP address.

I'v not tested this for Glue. How about setting VPC and that NAT gateway for the Glue job ?

Comment: Thanks @hir for the answer. But while creation of AWS job there is no configuration for VPC. So how to determine from which VPC the job will run?

Comment: Hi, @adtya. There is a VPC config in the "Glue > Databases > Connections > Add connection".

Comment: But according to [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/populate-add-connection.html) it does not support mongo as publicly accessible database(no jdbc support for mongo).